# How to import pairs of bson/json files

Tags: json, mongodb, import, bson

I have a few pairs of bson/json files. I know how to import bson files, but how to do with the json files? Should I import them in a particular order if at all?

Answer (score 0):

You can import JSON files by specifying the `type` in `mongoimport` command like this,

```
mongoimport --db <db name> --collection <collection name> --type json --file example.json --jsonArray
```

Comment: but how to do with the json files? Should I import them in a particular order if at all?

Comment: my question isn't how I can import them but should I?